# Apache Ignite IGFS: Start reading large file before write completes

Tags: java, ignite

I have a use case where I might be writing a 100 G file to my new IGFS store.  I want to start reading the beginning of the file before the end of the file has finished writing, as writing 100G could take a minute or two.

Since I can't speed up my hardware, I would like to speed up the software by beginning to read the file before I've closed my write stream.  I have several GB written out, so there is plenty of data to start reading.  When I write a simple test for this case, though, I get an exception thrown because IGFS doesn't seem to let me read from a stream when I am still writing to it.  Not unreasonable... except that I know under the hood that the first segments of the file are written and done with.

Does anyone know how I might get around this?  I suppose I could write a bunch of code to break files into 500M segments or something, but I am hoping that will be unessecary.

Comment: I would really recommend you to avoid IGFS when having 100G files.

Comment: Oh my.  Would you say there is a documented sweet spot somewhere for igfs?  Don't people use it in front of hadoop all the time, and hadoop often stores huge files?

Comment: It is mainly used to decrease latency when working with large number or small files. Moreover, Ignite project considers dropping IGFS altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Ignite in the IGFS mode, deploy it in the standard configuration - as separate [memory-centric storage](https://ignite.apache.org/arch/memorycentric.html) with enabled native persistence. Let Ignite store a subset of the data you have in Hadoop that is used by operations need to be accelerated. This configuration allows using all the Ignite APIs including Spark Integration.